# Casting issue in derby database

Tags: sql, casting, derby

here is my derby code in derby

```
select cast(3105.41 as number(17,2)) as asset
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

I get encountered "(" error.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number` is not a [data type](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/crefsqlj31068.html) in Derby use `numeric` or `decimal`.

```
select cast(3105.41 as decimal(17,2)) as asset
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: Thanks. I never work with this DB and would not have guessed the reason could be variable type. http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/crefsqlj31068.html

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev No problem glad I could help! Just a ? though, are you the OP?

Comment: Yakshemash. I am not the OP, in case you were wondering if he has multiple accounts. I try to learn as much as I can from the SQL questions.